# Pylons Google App Engine installation raise an error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pylons

I used latest version of GAE.
I try install Pylons v1.0 with this help article:
http://countergram.com/pylons-google-app-engine

paster serve --reload development.ini
work fine

Apache2+wsgi work fine

But: dev_appserver.py pylons
I have got error message:

> INFO:root:Starting admin server at: [Link to localhost:8000  ERROR]
>   2013-07-11 11:55:07,816 cgi.py:121] Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/evgeny/PycharmProjects/pylons/app.py", line 41, in
>     run_wsgi_app(loadapp('config:development.ini',
>   relative_to=appdir))  File
>   "lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 247, in
>   loadapp  ret*emphasized text*urn loadobj(APP, uri, name=name, **kw)  File
>   "lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 271, in
>   loadobj  global_conf=global_conf)  File
>   "lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 296, in
>   loadcontext  global_conf=global_conf)  File
>   "lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 320, in
>   _loadconfig  return loader.get_context(object_type, name, global_conf)  File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 454,
>   in get_context  section)  File
>   "lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 476, in
>   _context_from_use  object_type, name=use, global_conf=global_conf)  File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 406,
>   in get_context  global_conf=global_conf)  File
>   "lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 296, in
>   loadcontext  global_conf=global_conf)  File
>   "lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 328, in
>   _loadegg  return loader.get_context(object_type, name, global_conf)  File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 620,
>   in get_context  object_type, name=name)  File
>   "lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 646, in
>   find_egg_entry_point  possible.append((entry.load(), protocol,
>   entry.name))  File
>   "lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.19-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py",
>   line 1991, in load  entry = **import**(self.module_name,
>   globals(),globals(), ['**name**'])  File
>   "project/project/config/middleware.py", line 9, in   from
>   routes.middleware import RoutesMiddleware  File
>   "lib/python2.7/site-packages/routes/**init**.py", line 140, in
>     from routes.mapper import Mapper  File
>   "lib/python2.7/site-packages/routes/mapper.py", line 7, in  
>   from repoze.lru import LRUCache  ImportError: No module named
>   repoze.lru

Comment: You can't run out of virtualenv or site installed packages (such as repoze etc.)  You need to copy all of these into your project.  There are many similiar questions all over stack overflow.  Look at the error `ImportError: No module named repoze.lru`

Comment: Have a look at a current (you article is 3 years old) tutorial on getting pyramid running https://github.com/jensens/pyramid-gae-tutorial  which is where pylons has gone.  Pylons 1.x is pretty much a dead end. http://www.pylonsproject.org/projects/pylons-framework/about

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple decision.
At virtualenv path:

```
touch lib/python2.7/site-packages/repoze/__init__.py
```